# Reward based video is not working, unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I have developed an app in unity 3d and I have used google mobile ads plugin. Banner ad, interstitial ad is working fine. But rewarded video is not working!

In admob, adunit mediation, there is showing pending status beside to each third party ad unit. I am using chartboost, adcolony and unity ads third party ad network in admob.

Where is the problem? .

Comment: What is android version on device you testing on?

Comment: I am using android version 6.0.1

Comment: Are you 100% sure that everything is setup in dashboard/console? Show us some screenshots of configuration and a code how you calling ads.